# Xamarin SecureStorage doesn't work for UWP but works on Android, iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp

I am trying to use the `Xamarin.Essentials` `SecureStorage` . On Android and iOS it works perfectly, but on UWP, the `Get` always returns null.

My code:

storing the token:

```
await SecureStorage.SetAsync("tkn","mytoken123");
```

getting the token:

```
var token = await SecureStorage.GetAsync("tkn");
```

On UWP result is just null. No error no nothing. try catch doesn't do anything.

Any hints?

Or alternatives for a secure storage? `Xamarin Preferences` is what i use now, but it's not encrypted.

Comment: we can't reproduce your problem in UWP platform. please check if you used correct `key` , and check if set value before get it.

Comment: Do i need any ```appxmanifest``` settings?

Comment: No,  the data will store in to app's sandbox, it does not need other capability.

Comment: Interesting as I appear to have the same issue works on Android and iOS but not UWP, did you find a solution?

Comment: More like a Workaround.. a package called CrossSecureStorage now does the work for us. So don't waste your time  trying to implement it for UWP on your own (thats what I did and it worked, but I think Using CrossSecureStorage is easier ..) :D
https://github.com/sameerkapps/SecureStorage